# I need to create a clause over the query that I did

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code and i don't know so much about mysql and need filter a result.

```
SELECT reinc, 
       Round(( Count(reinc) * 1.0 / (SELECT Count(1) 
                                     FROM   `gi35` 
                                     WHERE  fi_auto = 'S' 
                                            AND ( uf = 'CE' 
                                                   OR uf = 'MA' 
                                                   OR uf = 'PI' ) 
                                            AND periodo = '01/10/2017') ) * 100, 
       2) AS 
       porcento, 
       Count(reinc) 
FROM   `gi35` 
WHERE  fi_auto = 'S' 
       AND ( uf = 'CE' 
              OR uf = 'MA' 
              OR uf = 'PI' ) 
       AND periodo = '01/10/2017' 
GROUP  BY reinc
```

this code return this:

[image]

I would like get only the value 40,92

Could someone help me?

Comment: Left justified SQL is very hard to read. Make it easy to help you, format properly!

Comment: If you can add relevant sample/result data in flat format instead of an image that helps a lot as an image is hard to do anything with. See this (doesn't only apply to code) [**Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) You can also use tools such as [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com) to create a working demo of your issue which other can play around with then.

Comment: What is the logic on why you choose `40.92` over `59.08` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT Round( Count(*) * 1.0 /
              (SELECT Count(*) 
               FROM `gi35` g2
               WHERE g2.fi_auto = 'S' AND g2.uf IN ('CE', 'MA', 'PI')
                     g2.periodo = '2017-10-01'
              ) * 100, 2
             ) AS porcento
FROM `gi35` g
WHERE g.fi_auto = 'S' AND g.uf IN ('CE', 'MA', 'PI') AND
      g.periodo = '2017-10-01' AND reinc = 'S';
```

I assumed `periodo` is a date and used the standard, non-ambiguous date format.

You could also shorten the query to:

```
SELECT Round( AVG(reinc = 'S') * 100, 2) AS porcento
FROM `gi35` g
WHERE g.fi_auto = 'S' AND g.uf IN ('CE', 'MA', 'PI') AND
      g.periodo = '2017-10-01' AND reinc = 'S';
```